# Arity mismatch when constructing a child record type

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs

I have a `point` record type defined as follows:

```
(define-record-type point
    (make-point x y)
    point?
    (x point-x)
    (y point-y)   

)
```

Now, I want to extend the `point` record type and define a new record type as follows:

```
(define-record-type cpoint 
    (make-cpoint color)
    cpoint?
    (color cpoint-color)   
    (parent point)    
)
```

When I run the above to definitions in the scheme shell everything works fine. I can construct `point` types properly. However, when I try to construct the `cpoint` type as follows:

```
(define p2 (make-cpoint 8 9 'red))
```

I get the following error:

> ; ...rfi/9/record.rkt:100:28: arity mismatch;;  the expected number of
>   arguments does not match the given number;   expected: 1;   given: 3;
>   [,bt for context]

I thought since `cpoint` is child of `point`, it should have accepted the arguments to the `point` type in its constructor.

How can I make this work?

P.S I am new to Scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no child records in SRFI-9. Thus you need to specify them independently:

```scm
(define-record-type cpoint 
  (make-cpoint x y color)
  cpoint?
  (x cpoint-x)
  (y cpoint-y)
  (color cpoint-color))
```

Thus the accessors to get `x` and `y` for `cpoint` and `point` are different.

## Alternatives that has parents

In R6RS you have [`(rnrs records syntactic (6))`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-7.html) which is similar to SRFI-9, but not compatible. Your code would look like:

```scm
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs records syntactic))

(define-record-type (point make-point point?)
  (fields (immutable x point-x)
          (immutable y point-y)))

(define-record-type (cpoint make-cpoint cpoint?)
  (fields (immutable c cpoint-c))
  (parent point))


(make-cpoint 4 5 'red) ; ==>  implementation chosen visual representation, perhaps #cpoint-4-5-red
```

You have tagged Racket and if you are using the default language, `#lang racket`, they have `struct`:

```scm
#lang racket

(struct point (x y) #:transparent) 
(struct cpoint point (color) #:transparent) 

(cpoint 4 5 'red) ; ==>  (cpoint 4 5 'red)
```

I added `#:transparent` since it is the default in R6RS. Of you really want the constructor name to be `make-xxx` you need to specify it:

```scm
#lang racket

(struct point (x y)
  #:constructor-name make-point
  #:transparent) 

(struct cpoint point (color)
  #:constructor-name make-cpoint
  #:transparent) 

(make-cpoint 4 5 'red) ; ==>  (cpoint 4 5 'red)
```